# Java: Paint Method Doesn't Run

Tags: java, methods, paint

I've looked at several other posts, and I have yet to find a clear answer. I don't entirely understand the paint method, which is probably my problem, but nowhere can I find a clear explanation. Can someone help me get this one working? The issue is that the paint method is not running. Everything else seems to work fine, but I do not see the oval I tell the program to render in the frame.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestObject extends Component {

    MouseResponder mouseListener = new MouseResponder();            // Creates a new mouse listener.

    WindowResponder windowListener = new WindowResponder();         // Creates a new window listener.

    Frame mainFrame = new Frame();                              // Makes a new frame.

public TestObject() {

    mainFrame.setSize(400,500);                                 // Makes the new frame 400 by 500 in size.

    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                      // Sets the location of the window to center it.

    mainFrame.setTitle("A Test program!");                      // Sets frame label.

    mainFrame.setBackground(new Color(199,199,199));            // Sets the background color of the window.

    mainFrame.addWindowListener(windowListener);                // Adds the window listener so close works.

    mainFrame.addMouseListener(mouseListener);                  // Adds the mouse listener to the frame.

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);                                 // Makes the new frame visible.

    System.out.println("[TestObject] Window" +                  // Prints a console message when main window is launched.
            " configured and launched.");


}

public void paint(Graphics pane) {

    System.out.println("[TestObject] Painting.");

    pane.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pane.drawOval(10,10,10,10);

}
```

}

Other Info:

- MouseResponder and WindowResponder are separate functioning classes.
- The TestObject class seen above is called by a main class which
  creates a new TestObject. The frame displays successfully as I
  specify.

Thank you for any help!
-Docithe

Comment: What exactly is your question? Any problems with the code or do you just not understand what `paint` does?

Comment: The paint method does not run. I don't know how to modify this code to make it work. The oval in the code above does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paint()` is responsible for rendering a component when it is visible.
At least in your code snippet, you did not add the test-component to the frame - thus, it is not displayed and not painted.

```
public TestObject() {
    //...
    mainFrame.add( this );
    //...
}
```

This still might not work because your Test Component is 0x0 pixel.
So you also

```
@Override
getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension( 20, 20 );
}
```

Comment: Adding the component is what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are late for your homework buddy !

- Take a new java file.
- Create a class
- Make it extend JFrame
- override the paint method
- put a println in it
- Take a second file
- put a main in it
- instanciate your first class and call show

move the window around, println should print out, meaning your code in paint is executing.
That's the way to do it in OOP, and for sure in java. Read more.

Comment: I do not use JFrame, I use Frame.

Comment: you should. AWT is obsolete, use swing or swt

Comment: I'm learning with AWT, and I'd like to get it working using that.

Comment: I've done plenty of reading. As you said, AWT is outdated, so it's hard to find any good information on it. Alex solved it for me, but I appreciate you trying.

Comment: forget it, you are gonna learn useless stuff. Go on with swing, it's standard.

Comment: I'm not self-taught. I'm taking a course, and we're using AWT, but I'm jumping ahead. Thanks anyway for your input.

Comment: my pleasure. But follow my advice, use swing.

Comment: @Doucithe: Use whatever graphics library your instructor tells you you must use. Then later when coding for fun, use Swing. But right now, whatever the instructor (and later substitute "boss") says, goes.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing two things here, creating a frame and creating a component. If I understand you correctly, you want to create a frame and within that frame have a custom component draw an oval.

The component is just this:

```
public class TestObject extends Component {
    public void paint(Graphics pane) {
        System.out.println("[TestObject] Painting.");
        pane.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pane.drawOval(10,10,10,10);
    }
}
```

and your main program looks more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MouseResponder mouseListener = new MouseResponder();
    WindowResponder windowListener = new WindowResponder();
    Frame mainFrame = new Frame();
    mainFrame.setSize(400,500);
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setTitle("A Test program!");
    mainFrame.setBackground(new Color(199,199,199));
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(windowListener);
    mainFrame.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    mainFrame.add(new TestObject());
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I am not saying this code will run, but it splits the two things in what they should be, a main program creating the frame, and a component painting an oval. I agree with Snicolas on the reading more...

Comment: My reason for asking was that I was trying to find a solution online, but all I can find is JFrame and JComponent. It's hard to find information on AWT, at least from what I saw. I've been "reading" information about this topic for two days before I finally gave up. Thank you for helping me better organize my code.